# C++: Uninitialized variables garbage

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, ram

```
int myInt;
cout << myInt; // Garbage like 429948, etc
```

If I output and/or work with uninitialized variables in C++, what are their assumed values?

- Actual values in the memory from the "last user"?

e.g.: Program A is closed, it had an int with the value `1234` at `0x1234` -> I run my program, `myInt` gets the address `0x1234`, I output it like above -> 1234

- Is it just random garbage?

Comment: Aren't there security conscious OSes that initialize all initialize memory so that you don't get to see what was left there by another process or another user?

Comment: Garbage, yes, but esp. for stack variables more dangerous than just "random". Since the value is determined by previous execution path, you end up with really weird bugs.

Comment: @Paul: If the OS behaves that way, you still end up with garbage.  Its just not garbage that has anything to do with other processes/users.

Answer (score 11):

"Random garbage" but with emphasis on "garbage", **not** on "random" – i.e., absolutely arbitrary garbage without even any guarantee of "randomness" – the compiler and runtime systems are allowed to have absolutely anything there (some systems may always give zeros, other might give arbitrary different values, etc., etc.).

Comment: arbitrary garbage is definitely a better description

Answer (score 5):

It's not even guaranteed to be a value at all. Trying to read the int, anything can happen (such as a signal sent causing your program to terminate). With particular importance in real life programming, switching on a not initialized `bool` can cause you hit neither `true` nor `false` cases.

Comment: I'm not sure the first part of that is true. Certainly the value of the int is indeterminate, but it has a well-defined location on the stack that the program can legally access, so I can't see any circumstance in which accessing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Tyler the standard say it's undefined behavior if it's not initialized (see 4.1/1). It may contain any bit pattern whatsoever, including a trap representation.

Comment: How would it segfault.  I am having a hard time believing that part.

Comment: Undefined behavior can, in theory, cause literally anything to happen. So if litb is right that it is UB, it could segfault. However, I'm having trouble finding where in the C++ standard it says that this is UB. 4.1.1 talks about UB for converting uninitialized *objects* into rvalues, but it doesn't seem to apply to fundamental types, and 3.9.6 confirms what he said about bools, but doesn't apply to ints.

Comment: @Tyler why does it not apply to fundamental types? Also, 3.9.1/6 does not confirm what i say. It's a non-normative foot-note only. 4.1/1 is what confirms what i said. @Tim, anything can happen when you have undefined behavior. If the int contains a certain bit-pattern, and that pattern when read is defined as invalid (not mapped to an integer value), the operation system can kill your program. There *are* systems out there that have such patterns, called "trap representations". Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx . Please explain your downvote.

Comment: @litb You're correct. On re-reading, 3.9.1/6 does say it is UB. The words immediately before the part about being uninitialized that refer to "not being derived from `T`" had me thinking only in the context of class types. Also, I didn't downvote you; In fact I'm upvoting this now that you've helped me find where the C++ standard backs it up. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

Its value is indeterminate. (§8.5/9)

There's no use trying to get meaningful data from it. In practice, it's just whatever happened to be there.

Most compilers will pack "meaningful" debug data in there in a debug build. For example, MSVC will initialize things to 0xCCCCCCCC. This is removed in an optimized build, of course.

Comment: 0xCCCCCCCC is interesting because in x86, 0xCC is the debug interrupt (int3) instruction.  Hence, if somehow the program tried to execute instructions from the unitialized memory (say due to a buffer overrun or some other such bug), it would immediately break into a debugger, permit a debugger to be attached, dump core, or some other similar OS-dependent function.

Answer (score 2):

the integer is a variable on the stack since it is a local variable. As long as it has not been initialized, the data on the stack is as-is. It is (part of) a previously used data. So it is garbage, but it is not random since given the executable and a begin state, the value is predictable. Predicting is hard since you have to take into the account the OS, the compiler, etc and moreover it is very pointless.

Answer (score 2):

> Program A is closed, it had an int with the value 1234 at 0x1234 -> I run my program, myInt gets the address 0x1234...

Note also that because of virtual memory in modern operating system what Program A called address 0x1234 is unlikely to actually refer to the same space in physical memory as what your program calls address 0x1234.